# discord.js Cannot read property add of undefined when trying to give role

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js

```
for (let l = 0; l < client.config.topMemberCount; l++) {
    if (topMemberList[l] === null) continue;
    if (String(topMemberList[l]) === '261292565247252480') continue;
    let roleMember = message.guild.members.fetch(topMemberList[l]);
    console.log(roleMember);
    let roleToGive = message.guild.roles.fetch('791984048851124234');
    roleMember.roles.add(roleToGive);
}
```

Alright, so:

- `client.config.topMemberCount` can be read, the value is **5**
- `topMemberList` is an Array which contains the IDs of 5 Users in String format (for example: *`223212312432123'*)
- When I run this, it returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`, which is weird, since if i output roleMember and roleToGive to console, it clearly seems to output a Snowflake of the role or member that is targeted.
- `if (topMemberList[l] === null) continue;` and `if (String(topMemberList[l]) === '261292565247252480') continue;` are just some measures to not give the role to myself or a null-object, should the array contain null at some point.

What am I doing wrong? :(

---

**Edit:** discord.js is on version 12.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `.fetch()` is asynchronous and returns a `Promise`, not a `GuildMember` or `Role` object. This is because it will take DJS a bit of time to fetch these values, and you need to only use the fetched member/role once it truly has been fetched (currently you are attempting to use these values before they have truly been fetched, which is why the error is telling you that `roleMember.roles` is undefined). Look at any [example](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) for `.fetch()` on the discord.js docs to see for yourself.

The solution would be either to use `async/await`, or to use `.then()`. I will demonstrate the latter below, because your `function` declaration is not provided (needless to say, you would just need to add `async` before `function` and `await` before your `.fetch()` lines).

```
for (let l = 0; l < client.config.topMemberCount; l++) {
    if (topMemberList[l] === null) continue;
    if (String(topMemberList[l]) === '261292565247252480') continue;
    
    message.guild.members.fetch(topMemberList[l]).then(roleMember => {
        
        message.guild.roles.fetch('791984048851124234').then(roleToGive => {
            roleMember.roles.add(roleToGive);
        }).catch(err => console.log("Role could not be found; Error: " + err.stack));

    }).catch(err => console.log("Member could not be found; Error: " + err.stack));
}
```

I also added `.catch()` statements, which should be able to show you any additional errors in this part of your code (in the event that the above fix is not enough to get your code working).